# what's wrong with rgbdslam?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### i have followed the wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam. and i have try  sequence at the bottom of rgbdslam's wiki page. everything seems ok. but when i type :rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg . i got the massage:
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/lg/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121023-105508
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam'] to:
['rgbdslam']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make clean ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make clean ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp [ make clean ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make clean ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make clean ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make clean ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make clean ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make clean ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make clean ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rgbdslam [PASS] [ 0.25 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbdslam: 100.8 sec ]                                                                                        [ 1 Active 30/31 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ 41%] Generating src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx
[ 43%] Generating src/moc_qtros.cxx
[ 46%] Generating src/moc_openni_listener.cxx
[ 48%] Generating src/moc_qt_gui.cxx
[ 51%] Generating src/moc_graph_manager.cxx
[ 53%] Generating src/moc_glviewer.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target rgbdslam
make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/lg/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build' make[3]: 正在进入目录` /home/lg/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
[ 56%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/gicp-fallback.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/qtros.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/qt_gui.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/node.o
[ 71%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/glviewer.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/parameter_server.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/ros_service_ui.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/misc.o
[ 84%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/sift_gpu_wrapper.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_qtros.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_openni_listener.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_qt_gui.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_graph_manager.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_glviewer.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/moc_ros_service_ui.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rgbdslam
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o:openni_listener.cpp:function OpenNIListener::retrieveTransformations(std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >, Node*): error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o:openni_listener.cpp:function OpenNIListener::retrieveTransformations(std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >, Node*): error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o:openni_listener.cpp:function OpenNIListener::processNode(Node*): error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.o:openni_listener.cpp:function OpenNIListener::processNode(Node*): error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
collect2: ld 返回 1
make[3]: *** [../bin/rgbdslam] 错误 1
make[3]:正在离开目录 `/home/lg/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] 错误 2 make[2]:正在离开目录` /home/lg/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
make[1]: *** [all] 错误 2
make[1]:正在离开目录 `/home/lg/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/lg/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121023-105508/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 100.79 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Cleaned 31 packages.
[ rosmake ] Built 31 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/lg/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121023-105508

how can i deal with the info ? i use ROS fuerte,ubuntu 11.10 64 bit. thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46521/what%27s-wrong-with-rgbdslam-?/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-10-22**:
@Felix Endres  @yygyt

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-22**:
Do not add people's names to comments just to notify them. If you tag your post correctly, people will see it and if they have time and know the answer, they will help.

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-23**:
sorry @longzhixi123, I don't have the answer to that.If I were you, as Felix suggested, I'd google the error.Maybe you would like to try to compile the code here http://goo.gl/MKTYg to see if it works fine. If so, it means librt is fine and you may want to check cmake file to verify linking with lrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add `rt` to the libraries to be linked.

Change

`SET(LIBS_LINK GL GLU ${G2O_LIBS} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS} -lboost_signals)`

in CMakeLists.txt to

`SET(LIBS_LINK rt GL GLU ${G2O_LIBS} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS} -lboost_signals)`

---

Originally posted by [Vikas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1768/vikas/) with karma: 106 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-11-18**:
thanks a lot , i have make the rgbdslam package ok http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Weird. clock_gettime is part of "ctime", so I wonder how this could fail to link. Also, I can not reproduce this error, so I can only suggest to google for "[error: undefined reference to 'clock_gettime' collect2: ld](https://www.google.com/search?q=error%3A+undefined+reference+to+%27clock_gettime%27+collect2%3A+ld)"

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1